# ubuntu-device-flash touch hangs at waiting from VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-touch, android, flash

Aim: to install Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 7.

Environment: I have installed Ubuntu Mate 1.10.2 in a VirtualBox machine (Win7 as host) and I can successfully connect to my device through adb and fastboot from this. I tried to follow this guide for the installation, but got stack at the (...) prompt when trying the fastboot oem unlock:
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/ 
Therefore I installed the windows SDK and managed to unlock it from there (Win7).

Problem: Now I would like to flash the device with Ubuntu Touch from my Ubuntu VirtualBox machine using the suggested command:

ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap

2015/12/18 17:32:00 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting

and then nothing happens. I first rebooted the Nexus 7 to the bootloader and I am able to see it from my Ubuntu machine with

username@VirtualBox:~$ fastboot devices

015d4906df480807       fastboot

So the question is, how do I keep going? Can I flash it from windows instead? Can I use some "channel"-command or which image should I download? I cannot find any grouper images anymore, would generic images work?

My apologies if it is a duplicate post. It is very similar to many other posts but I honestly did not find one with the same circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that the 2012 version of Nexus 7, called "grouper", is no longer supported by Ubuntu Touch. 
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/devices/

I found a few other posts trying to solve this, by installing the latest Touch supported, but for now (today 21. dec 2015) I have not found a working solution.
[Installing Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 7 (2012) now that it is no longer supported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633788/installing-ubuntu-touch-on-nexus-7-2012-now-that-it-is-no-longer-supported)

So the bottom line right now is that I "downgraded" to Android 4.3 over the official Google page, using the windows version of fastboot, and skipping to update the bootloader 4.23, as this is not needed and there is a bug covering this.
https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/