# Ubuntu Touch stuck at terminal

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, tablet, nexus-7

After intalling Ubuntu Touch, my Google Nexus 2012 Wifi Tablet stuck at this screen
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttFMr.jpg)

*adb devices* does not detect any devices.

Can you help me?

Comment: The Nexus 2012 is not a supported tablet, so I'm not sure how you would have installed Ubuntu on it, given there's no image on the server. You should reboot to the bootloader or recovery if possible, and restore an Android image to that device.

Comment: I used a port version. It is not official. I followed the instruction in this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/633788/installing-ubuntu-touch-on-nexus-7-2012-now-that-it-is-no-longer-supported.

I am not able to go to the recovery screen. The button combination does not do anything. 

Is there any way to install Android on an empty device?

Comment: Yes, you must reboot into the bootloader by holding power and volume up (i think, maybe it is down) buttons until the fastboot screen appears. Then you can use the fastboot tool.

Comment: Can you detect it with fastboot?